# Python table titles into dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I am using `numpy.loadtxt` to extract a large array of data from a text file and then using a loop to put different columns into different dictionary keys like this:

```
f = numpy.loadtxt(datafile, skiprows=5) # Open and read in the file, skipping to the data
d = {} # Create empty dictionary

for x in range(0, f.shape[1]):
    d[x] = f[:,x]     # Loop through the columns of the datafile, putting each one into
#a dictionary index
```

The row above the array in the text file contains all the titles for the variables in the array, is there a way to get each variable name and put it as the key name for the relevant dictionary? (ie, column one = data, d[date]={14/11/12,15/11/12 .... etc)

Comment: do you mean i"column one = date" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas is a good idea, so "thumbs up" to the answer by reptilicus.

If you don't want the dependency on Pandas, you can just as easily use the function `numpy.genfromtxt` to read the data directly into a numpy structured array.  A structure array acts like both a numpy 1-d array and a dictionary.

For example, here's a sample data file, "data.csv":

```
alpha, beta, gamma
100, 0.5, 19.9
210, 0.25, 21.0
240, 0.45, 15.0
290, 0.75, 5.5
```

You can read this into a structured array as follows:

```
>>> data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=None)
```

The option `names=True` tells `genfromtxt` to use the columns headings as the field names in the structured array.  Setting `dtype=None` tells `genfromtxt` to figure out the data type of the columns automatically (the default is to convert all values to double precision floating point values).

`data` looks like this.

```
>>> data
array([(100, 0.5, 19.9), (210, 0.25, 21.0), (240, 0.45, 15.0),
       (290, 0.75, 5.5)], 
      dtype=[('alpha', '<i4'), ('beta', '<f8'), ('gamma', '<f8')])
```

You can access individual elements (each is a structure containing three fields):

```
>>> data[0]
(100, 0.5, 19.9)
```

Or you can access columns using the dictionary-like interface:

```
>>> data['beta']
array([ 0.5 ,  0.25,  0.45,  0.75])
```

And you can combine those:

```
>>> data['beta'][1]
0.25
>>> data[1]['beta']
0.25
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to use the excellent Pandas library here. You can certainly do what you are looking for yourself, but Pandas provides some nice I/O routines, and also has a lot of datetime functionality builtin. For instance:

```
In [747]: print open('foo.csv').read()
date,A,B,C
20090101,a,1,2
20090102,b,3,4
20090103,c,4,5

In [748]: data = read_csv('foo.csv')
Out[748]:
   date  A  B  C
0  20090101  a  1  2
1  20090102  b  3  4
2  20090103  c  4  5
```

That creates a data frame, similar to a record array in Numpy. You can access the columns like you want, with data['date'], data['A'], etc.

More info [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)